# What am I missing about Java script, please help me?

Tags: javascript

I have a game that is html version, and cotains some java script codes, there is a question and 4 answers option, and one of them is correct, there is a lifeline that asking audience that gives percentange, but origin of codes gives always random percentange, and I would like it to give always correct answer, what Should I do?

```
function calculateGraphPercentages(){
var percentageOfDifficulty = (window.GameVariables.QuestionLevel - 1) * 5;
var beDevious = (Math.random() * 100) > 90 ? true : false;

if(window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut == true){
    window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] = 0;
}

if(window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut == true){
    window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] = 0;
}

if(window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut == true){
    window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] = 0;
}

if(window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut == true){
    window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] = 0;
}

if(beDevious != true){
    if(window.GameVariables.CurrentCorrectAnswer == "A" && window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut == false){
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - percentageOfDifficulty));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] = window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] = window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] = window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut == true ? 0 : 100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1]  - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2];
    }

    if(window.GameVariables.CurrentCorrectAnswer == "B" && window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut == false){
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - percentageOfDifficulty));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] = window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] = window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] = window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut == true ? 0 : 100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2]  - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3];
    }

    if(window.GameVariables.CurrentCorrectAnswer == "C" && window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut == false){
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - percentageOfDifficulty));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] = window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] = window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] = window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut == true ? 0 : 100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3]  - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0];
    }

    if(window.GameVariables.CurrentCorrectAnswer == "D" && window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut == false){
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - percentageOfDifficulty));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] = window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] = window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] = window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut == true ? 0 : 100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0]  - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1];
    }
}
else{
    if(window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut == false){
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] = window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] = window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] = window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut == true ? 0 : 100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1]  - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2];
    }

    if(window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut == false){
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] = window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] = window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] = window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut == true ? 0 : 100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2]  - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3];
    }

    if(window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut == false){
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] = window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] = window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] = window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut == true ? 0 : 100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3]  - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0];
    }

    if(window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut == false){
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] = window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] = window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut == true ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0]));
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] = window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut == true ? 0 : 100 - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0]  - window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1];
    }
}

var sumOfAllPercents = window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] + window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] + window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] + window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3];

if(sumOfAllPercents < 100){
    if(window.GameVariables.CurrentCorrectAnswer == "A" && window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut == false){
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] += 100 - sumOfAllPercents;
    }

    if(window.GameVariables.CurrentCorrectAnswer == "B" && window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut == false){
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] += 100 - sumOfAllPercents;
    }

    if(window.GameVariables.CurrentCorrectAnswer == "C" && window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut == false){
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] += 100 - sumOfAllPercents;
    }

    if(window.GameVariables.CurrentCorrectAnswer == "D" && window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut == false){
        window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] += 100 - sumOfAllPercents;
    }
}

window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0] = window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[0]/100;
window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1] = window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[1]/100;
window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2] = window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[2]/100;
window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3] = window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents[3]/100;
```

Comment: why do you take `window`?

Comment: Why not have an array of objects which have the desired structure, pick and display one, validate the answer therein. The current setup seem very copy and paste and violates the rules of DRY

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are "missing something about Java script", it seems like you are having problems with calculations in a piece of code.  The title seems very misleading to me.

Comment: Yes, actually I am not a expert, I am consumer and playing my friends, about I realized that it can be change, but I dont know how it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would follow this sort of pattern when refactoring code like this...

```
function calculateGraphPercentages() {
    var percentageOfDifficulty = (window.GameVariables.QuestionLevel - 1) * 5;
    var beDevious = (Math.random() * 100) > 90 ? true : false;
    var i;

    /*
     * First off, code is way more readable with smaller variable names.
     * Don't be afraid to store things with long names in variables
     */
    var votingPercents = window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents;
    var currentAnswer = window.GameVariables.CurrentCorrectAnswer;

    var answerAIsOut = window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut;
    var answerBIsOut = window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut;
    var answerCIsOut = window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut;
    var answerDIsOut = window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut;

    /*
     * When you want to do the same thing to something multiple times, you 
     * want to use a loop
     * You might also want to look into using switch/case over if/else 
     * whenever it makes sense
     */
    var answers = [answerAIsOut, answerBIsOut, answerCIsOut, answerDIsOut];

    for (i = 0 ; i < answers.length ; i++) {
        if (answers[i]) {
            votingPercents[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    /*
     * So that things are simplified to numbers, why not put A, B, C, and D 
     * into an array?
     */

    var possibleAnswers = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

    /* 
     * You don't need to compare anything to true, if (true) evaluates to true
     * so we can replace all those comparisons to condense the code a bit
     */

    if (!beDevious) {
        if (currentAnswer == possibleAnswers[0] && !answers[0]) {
            votingPercents[0] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - percentageOfDifficulty));
            votingPercents[1] = answers[1] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[0]));
            votingPercents[2] = answers[2] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[0] - votingPercents[1]));
            votingPercents[3] = answers[3] ? 0 : 100 - votingPercents[0] - votingPercents[1]  - votingPercents[2];
        }

        if (currentAnswer == possibleAnswers[1] && !answers[1]) {
            votingPercents[1] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - percentageOfDifficulty));
            votingPercents[2] = answers[2] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[1]));
            votingPercents[3] = answers[3] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[1] - votingPercents[2]));
            votingPercents[0] = answers[0] ? 0 : 100 - votingPercents[1] - votingPercents[2]  - votingPercents[3];
        }

        if (currentAnswer == possibleAnswers[2] && !answers[2]) {
            votingPercents[2] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - percentageOfDifficulty));
            votingPercents[3] = answers[3] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[2]));
            votingPercents[0] = answers[0] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[2] - votingPercents[3]));
            votingPercents[1] = answers[1] ? 0 : 100 - votingPercents[2] - votingPercents[3]  - votingPercents[0];
        }

        if (currentAnswer == possibleAnswers[3] && !answers[3]) {
            votingPercents[3] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - percentageOfDifficulty));
            votingPercents[0] = answers[0] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[3]));
            votingPercents[1] = answers[1] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[3] - votingPercents[0]));
            votingPercents[2] = answers[2] ? 0 : 100 - votingPercents[3] - votingPercents[0]  - votingPercents[1];
        }
    }
    else{
        if (!answers[0]) {
            votingPercents[0] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100));
            votingPercents[1] = answers[1] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[0]));
            votingPercents[2] = answers[2] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[0] - votingPercents[1]));
            votingPercents[3] = answers[3] ? 0 : 100 - votingPercents[0] - votingPercents[1]  - votingPercents[2];
        }

        if (!answers[1]) {
            votingPercents[1] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100));
            votingPercents[2] = answers[2] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[1]));
            votingPercents[3] = answers[3] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[1] - votingPercents[2]));
            votingPercents[0] = answers[0] ? 0 : 100 - votingPercents[1] - votingPercents[2]  - votingPercents[3];
        }

        if (!answers[2]) {
            votingPercents[2] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100));
            votingPercents[3] = answers[3] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[2]));
            votingPercents[0] = answers[0] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[2] - votingPercents[3]));
            votingPercents[1] = answers[1] ? 0 : 100 - votingPercents[2] - votingPercents[3]  - votingPercents[0];
        }

        if (!answers[3]) {
            votingPercents[3] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100));
            votingPercents[0] = answers[0] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[3]));
            votingPercents[1] = answers[1] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[3] - votingPercents[0]));
            votingPercents[2] = answers[2] ? 0 : 100 - votingPercents[3] - votingPercents[0]  - votingPercents[1];
        }
    }

    /*
     * Now let's do the same thing here as we did above and put this in a 
     * loop so we can easily add more items later if we need to
     */
    var sumOfAllPercents = 0;

    for (i = 0 ; i < votingPercents.length ; i++ ) {
        sumOfAllPercents += votingPercents[i];
    }

    if (sumOfAllPercents < 100) {
        for (i = 0 ; i < answers.length ; i++) {
            if (currentAnswer == possibleAnswers[i] && !answers[i]) {
                votingPercents[i] += 100 - sumOfAllPercents;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < votingPercents.length ; i++) {
        votingPercents[i] = votingPercents[i] / 100;
    }
}
```

### OK, so now your code is debuggable, let's start finding our algorithm:

```
function calculateGraphPercentages() {
    var percentageOfDifficulty = (window.GameVariables.QuestionLevel - 1) * 5;
    var beDevious = (Math.random() * 100) > 90 ? true : false;
    var i;


    /*
     * Instead of referencing global variables, why not pass all this info to calculateGraphPercentages like this:
     * calculateGraphPercentages(answers, votingPercents, currentAnswer)
     * or use some method to manage global state like Flux
     */
    var votingPercents = window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents;
    // Save the number of votes so we can reuse it
    var numVotes = votingPercents.length

    var currentAnswer = window.GameVariables.CurrentCorrectAnswer;

    var answerAIsOut = window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut;
    var answerBIsOut = window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut;
    var answerCIsOut = window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut;
    var answerDIsOut = window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut;

    /*
     * When you want to do the same thing to something multiple times, you 
     * want to use a loop
     * You might also want to look into using switch/case over if/else 
     * whenever it makes sense
     */
    var answers = [answerAIsOut, answerBIsOut, answerCIsOut, answerDIsOut];

    for (i = 0 ; i < numVotes ; i++) {
        if (answers[i]) {
            votingPercents[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    /*
     * So that you simplify things to just numbers, why not put 
     * A, B, C, and D into an array?
     * You could also make this extensible by iterating over the alphabet 
     * (or whatever set of characters you choose) and stopping at numVotes
     */

    var possibleAnswers = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

    /* 
     * Now you can try to find patterns in the numbers and figure out how to 
     * create a loop or recursive function to iterate through a progression 
     * of numbers so all this code is easier to read and not repeated.
     * DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself
     */

    /*
     * Let's start by putting common functionality into it's own function:
     */

     /*
            votingPercents[0] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - percentageOfDifficulty));
            votingPercents[1] = answers[1] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[0]));
            votingPercents[2] = answers[2] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - votingPercents[0] - votingPercents[1]));
            votingPercents[3] = answers[3] ? 0 : 100 - votingPercents[0] - votingPercents[1]  - votingPercents[2];
    */

    /*
     * We'll add a difficulty parameter so we can re-use this function in both places
     * We'll use the modulus operator to wrap around
     */
    function calcPercents(currentIndex, numIndexes, difficulty) {
        var votingPercents = [];
        var lastIndex = numIndexes + currentIndex;

        votingPercents[currentIndex] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * difficulty);
        var totalPercents = votingPercents[currentIndex];

        for (var i = currentIndex + 1; i <= lastIndex ; i++) {
            totalPercents += votingPercents[i % numIndexes]
            votingPercents[i % numIndexes] = answers[i % numIndexes] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - totalPercents))
        }
        votingPercents[lastIndex] = answers[lastIndex] ? 0 : 100 - totalPercents;
    }

    /*
     * Now we can reuse that function easily
     */

    if (!beDevious) {
        for (i = 0 ; i < numVotes ; i++) {
            calcPercents(i, numVotes, 100 - percentageOfDifficulty)
        }
    } else {
        for (i = 0 ; i < numVotes ; i++) {
            calcPercents(i, numVotes, 100)
        }
    }

    /*
     * Now let's do the same thing here as we did above and put this in a 
     * loop so we can easily add more items later if we need to
     */
    var sumOfAllPercents = 0;

    for (i = 0 ; i < numVotes ; i++ ) {
        sumOfAllPercents += votingPercents[i];
    }

    if (sumOfAllPercents < 100) {
        for (i = 0 ; i < numVotes ; i++) {
            if (currentAnswer == possibleAnswers[i] && !answers[i]) {
                votingPercents[i] += 100 - sumOfAllPercents;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < numVotes ; i++) {
        votingPercents[i] = votingPercents[i] / 100;
    }
}
```

### Great, now we have an algorithm.  Let's make the whole thing reusable and see what we've got

```
// A function that calculates the voting percentages based on a difficulty rating
function calcPercents(currentIndex, numIndexes, difficulty) {
    var votingPercents = [];
    var lastIndex = numIndexes + currentIndex;

    votingPercents[currentIndex] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * difficulty);
    var totalPercents = votingPercents[currentIndex];

    for (var i = currentIndex + 1; i <= lastIndex ; i++) {
        totalPercents += votingPercents[i % numIndexes]
        votingPercents[i % numIndexes] = answers[i % numIndexes] ? 0 : Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - totalPercents))
    }
    votingPercents[lastIndex] = answers[lastIndex] ? 0 : 100 - totalPercents;

    return votingPercents;
}

// A function that calculates graph percentages
function calculateGraphPercentages(answers, votingPercents, currentAnswer) {
    var percentageOfDifficulty = (window.GameVariables.QuestionLevel - 1) * 5;
    var beDevious = (Math.random() * 100) > 90 ? true : false;
    var i;

    // Save the number of votes so we can reuse it
    var numVotes = votingPercents.length;
    var possibleAnswers = [];
    var sumOfAllPercents = 0;

    for (i = 0 ; i < numVotes ; i++) {
        if (answers[i]) {
            votingPercents[i] = 0;
        }
        // Create an alpha-numeric list of answers
        possibleAnswers.push(String.fromCharCode(65 + 1));
    }

    if (!beDevious) {
        for (i = 0 ; i < numVotes ; i++) {
            votingPercents[i] = calcPercents(i, numVotes, 100 - percentageOfDifficulty)
        }
    } else {
        for (i = 0 ; i < numVotes ; i++) {
            votingPercents[i] = calcPercents(i, numVotes, 100)
        }
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < numVotes ; i++ ) {
        sumOfAllPercents += votingPercents[i];
    }

    if (sumOfAllPercents < 100) {
        for (i = 0 ; i < numVotes ; i++) {
            if (currentAnswer == possibleAnswers[i] && !answers[i]) {
                votingPercents[i] += 100 - sumOfAllPercents;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < numVotes ; i++) {
        votingPercents[i] = votingPercents[i] / 100;
    }
}
```

Then I would call it like this:

```
var votingPercents = window.GameVariables.AskTheAudienceVotingPercents;
var currentAnswer = window.GameVariables.CurrentCorrectAnswer;

var answerAIsOut = window.GameVariables.AnswerAIsOut;
var answerBIsOut = window.GameVariables.AnswerBIsOut;
var answerCIsOut = window.GameVariables.AnswerCIsOut;
var answerDIsOut = window.GameVariables.AnswerDIsOut;

var answers = [answerAIsOut, answerBIsOut, answerCIsOut, answerDIsOut];

calculateGraphPercentages(answers, votingPercents, currentAnswer);
```

But I would figure out how to get those values into the structures you're passing to the function first and keep them consistent across your app.

This code is much more reusable and easier to debug.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your great time sir, I am gonna check it, :)

Comment: Please note that I have not tested any of this code.  I'm just providing it as an example.

Comment: Thank you, but I could not solve it, app gives error, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Then, I'll have to have sample data and expected output... But really You're not asking for working code in your question, just how to improve.  Learn how to improve, don't just copy my code.

Comment: yes, I have just copied your code :) by the way I am not expert about this issues, so I dont have experience enough to improve. But thank you for your time, I really respect you sir.